# Can't set up ISAPI filter for tomcat on IIS

Tags: isapi-redirect

Windows XP SP3: try to set ISAPI filter isapi_redirect.dll in following way:
1. Create folder jakarta to point to the folder with the file isapi_redirect.dll. Set right permission on this folder.
2. Create virtual directo to point above folder
3. Set filter at localhost Level.

When it's done, restart IIS. And check the filter. it said not loaded with red arrow.

Same files were set on another XP computer  and works fine.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the directions here, but it sounds like you may have an incorrect property file, perhaps, or you may have downloaded an intel-based dll and used it on an amd machine.

Here are some directions to follow
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html

It would help if you look in the event log, on XP, and see what error may be present.